# Using d3.js to create a heatmap, having issues with color

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi i have a heatmap here that im trying to give color to. Right now its all over red but I want to use the d3.interpolateRdYlBu, i want my values that are lower to be the blue and the higher be the red so i would like it to gel nicely. I know that its reading correctly since i get the red and no other errors in my console but Im not doing something right that it doesnt take my value into account and do accordingly. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<!-- Load color palettes -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>

<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 80, right: 25, bottom: 30, left: 40},
  width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nataliemcg18/Data/master/NASA_Surface_Temperature.csv", function(data) {

  // Labels of row and columns -> unique identifier of the column called 'group' and 'variable'
  var myGroups = d3.map(data, function(d){return d.group;}).keys()
  var myVars = d3.map(data, function(d){return d.variable;}).keys()

  // Build X scales and axis:
  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ 0, width ])
    .domain(myGroups)
    .padding(0.05);
  svg.append("g")
    .style("font-size", 15)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0))
    .select(".domain").remove()

  // Build Y scales and axis:
  var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ height, 0 ])
    .domain(myVars)
    .padding(0.05);
  svg.append("g")
    .style("font-size", 15)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0))
    .select(".domain").remove()

  // Build color scale
  var myColor = d3.scaleSequential()
    .interpolator( d3.interpolateRdYlBu)
    .domain([1,100])



  // create a tooltip
  var tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("div")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("background-color", "white")
    .style("border", "solid")
    .style("border-width", "2px")
    .style("border-radius", "5px")
    .style("padding", "5px")

  // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
  var mouseover = function(d) {
    tooltip
      .style("opacity", 1)
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke", "green")
      .style("opacity", 1)
  }
  var mousemove = function(d) {
    tooltip
      .html("The exact value of this cell is: " + d.value,   )
      .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+70) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
  }
  var mouseleave = function(d) {
    tooltip
      .style("opacity", 0)
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke", "none")
      .style("opacity", 0.8)
  }

  // add the squares
  svg.selectAll()
    .data(data, function(d) {return d.group+':'+d.variable;})
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group) })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.variable) })
      .attr("rx", 4)
      .attr("ry", 4)
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
      .style("fill", function(d) { return myColor(d.value)} )
      .style("stroke-width", 4)
      .style("stroke", "none")
      .style("opacity", 0.8)
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
})

// Add title to graph
svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", -50)
        .attr("text-anchor", "left")
        .style("font-size", "22px")
        .text("A d3.js heatmap");

// Add subtitle to graph
svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("text-anchor", "left")
        .style("font-size", "14px")
        .style("fill", "grey")
        .style("max-width", 400)
        .text("A short description of the take-away message of this chart.");


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your colour scale, you've set the domain as [0,100]. Your values however are between 0 and 1.5, and you want them reversed

so, this should fix it:

```
  // Build color scale
  var myColor = d3.scaleSequential()
     .interpolator( d3.interpolateRdYlBu)
     .domain([1.3,0])
```

To be even more thorough, you can use the d3.max and d3.min functions to work out the max in min for you:

```
  var myColor = d3.scaleSequential()
    .interpolator( d3.interpolateRdYlBu)
    .domain([d3.max(data, d=>d.value),d3.min(data, d=>d.value)])
```

Heres a jsFiddle with this working: https://jsfiddle.net/x8zyud5t/

Comment: I see by your next question, that you answered this one yourself. Please ensure that if you do so before other people, that you put your own answer in - it may still be useful for people in the future.